# Create an Android app on ios (Apple) platform

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, chromium

This might sound like a duplicate question but trust me its not.

I have an Android app. It contains `WebView` to display webpages. Now I am planning to go live with the app on ios too. Now having two different codes and maintaining them is a difficult task.

Is there a way I can develop app in both the platforms with minimum maintenance issues. With minimum maintenance I mean more reusable code that can be use on both the platforms.

I have heard that it can be done using `Chromium Project` but am unable to find supporting docs for the same on internet.

Any suggestions?? or reference materials??

Comment: The Chromium project is the base project for the Chrome Browser and Chrome OS.

Comment: @Ridcully Thats what I understand but a client of us asked us to evaluate cross platform app development using Chromium Project and i am puzzled coz i have no idea if its even possible.

Comment: I guess he was aiming at some kind of HTML5/Javascript based cross-platform development, which you can certainly do and you can convert those Web-Apps to "native" apps using e.g. Phonegap. Phonegap is sort of a wrapper around your Web-App, so you can put it into the AppStore/PlayStore and it also provides you with Javascript APIs to access certain OS features like camera you cannot access with plain HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try one of the several frameworks out there, being PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com) an interesting option.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate `WebView` in PhoneGap??

Comment: Have you even looked at the project? The *whole thing* is a web view.

Comment: I have checked it now and I think it will serve my purpose. By the way is there any good tutorial/reference for PhoneGap?

Comment: In my opinition, you should read the API Documentation first. There's no better way to know what you can do: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/index.html

And for more concise problems you might face, you can always ask here, there'll probably be a lot of people able and willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know there is no way you could use your Java code and the XML files (including your `WebView`) in IOS application. the language/platform are different.

What you could do is to develop a web application that looks as a mobile application for example using JQueryMobile and the export it using the already suggested PhoneGap framework to any platform you would like.

Comment: can you refer any tutorial or reference material for PhoneGap use

Comment: actually PhoneGap got a great getting started guides on their site:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/index.html